# PostgreSQL cache function return value

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, functions, cache

Suppose I have defined a function that is expensive to compute. Is there a way to define an index in PostgreSQL to cache the return value for a given set of parameters?

For example, let's say that I have a function `stats(year, month)` to calculate some statistics for the given `year` and `month`. Is there a way to precompute the result for the years 2019, 2020, 2021 using an index or any other technique?

Comment: Why not just store the precomputed values in a table?  You can index the table if you want, but you can't have an index without a table.

Comment: If both parameters are take from a table, and the function returns a single value and is (truly) immutable you can create an index on that: `create index on the_table ((stats(year, month)))`